# How to make distinct list off words from large column of sentence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have large list of sentence about 18m records (2gb).

```
id       txt
---------------------------
1        Hi my name is Jim.
2        I love listing music.
   ....
```

I want to make new table with all distinct words.

```
id       word
---------------------------
1        Hi 
2        my
3        name  
   ...
```

What is the best way making that request, keeping in mind large database and execution time?
All sentence are FULLTEXT indexed.

Comment: If your table is backed by FULLTEXT, why do you need a word list?

Comment: This is going to be unreasonably difficult unless you use a client language like php or python.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes first table is backed by FULLTEXT

Comment: @O.Jones I was also thinking go with php through list, but its also take to long, it must be better way.  I need it for making some relations in other databases

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe crazy/naive/impossible - But you can try to:

- Dump all data into a text file with `SELECT txt FROM old_table INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'`
- Open the file with a decent text editor
- Find and replace all characters you don't need (like `. , ! ?`)
- Find and replace all whitespaces with `\n`
- `CREATE TABLE words (word VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY)`
- Import the data from file ignoring duplicates: `LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name' IGNORE INTO TABLE words`
- Alter the table to add the `id` column or use `INSERT .. SELECT ..` to copy the data to a new table.

Comment: Decent text editor with these large files doing same thing, execution time killing me. I try couple off them, I try direct in terminal but same thing unfortunately. Idea is good, I will try divide them in small groups and than try this. But I´m sure it must be some better way than this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method . . . it just requires scanning the table multiple times and assumes words are separated by a single space:

```
select substring_index(txt, ' ', 1) as word
from t
union all
select substring_index(substring_index(txt, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) as word
from t
where txt like '% %'
union all
select substring_index(substring_index(txt, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) as word
from t
where txt like '% % %'
union ll
. . .
```

The problem is that you have to keep adding subqueries up to the maximum number of words in the text.

In other words, SQL *can* do what you want.  However, it is not necessarily the optimal solution.  You might be better off reading the data into a tool like Python and then writing it out again to the database.